# Is it appropriate to delete answers with many down votes

Tags: discussion, vote-to-delete

I have to believe this has been asked before; however, I seem to be failing at searching. I decided recently to get involved reviewing posts in Stack Overflow, and encountered this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6830646

I considered the comments available for reviewers who vote to close an answer, and they do not include a close-this-because-the-community-overwhelmingly-considers-it-to-be-incorrect. Is this a valid reason to delete an answer, or is it better for the answer to remain open so as to stand against the poster's reputation?

**Edit:**

I've accepted the answer provided by Louis, as it points to official guidance against the practice of deleting answers merely because they are incorrect.

I'll add that I do not entirely agree with the guidance. It would seem that genuine answers that are blatantly incorrect, as determined by an overwhelming number of down votes, offers little of value to SO. Whether and how many down votes would warrant deletion were the guidance to change, however, is a different question entirely.

At any rate, thanks for helping me find the guidance. I will read it carefully and act accordingly.

Comment: I think it was okay to delete that answer, and voted to do so myself. It is literally not an answer -- it is a copy/paste from the question. There's nothing about that post to redeem it, make it useful, or add anything to anyone's understanding. He just copied to code the OP says doesn't work and insisted that it does work.

Comment: Just in the way of an update, the answer was deleted by community vote.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As much as I'd like to delete terrible answers, that's not the guidance we get from [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/241526) on Meta.S:

> For answers, any post that is not an answer (should be a comment, doesn't answer the question, etc.) should be deleted. **Answers that are wrong or that dispense poor advice should be downvoted, not deleted.**

(Emphasis mine. This is in the last section of the answer.)

Whether or not the answerer suffers from a reputation loss is not a factor.

Comment: While I agree with your emphasis and the principle in general - if it's a dangerously wrong answer, then it should go the way of the dodo - even more so if it's an accepted answer which weights it more heavily on the page, and someone else is going to run into trouble using it.

Comment: @JonClements If someone uses an answer with a lot of downvotes, he/she deserves to be run into trouble.

Comment: I think that if you've copied code from the OP which the OP says is wrong, pasted it in your answer with an insistence that it is right, without any other content, qualifying information, documentation, or commentary, then you have not posted an answer. You've posted spam, and it is okay to delete it.

Comment: This should be clarified to say that wrong answers shouldn't be deleted *through review*. They should be down voted so that sufficiently-privileged users can delete them (or the answerer).

Comment: I can't agree with this because there is [a badge for deleting downvoted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure), which means it is encouraged behavior.

Comment: @TylerH That is for deleting your **own** downvoted answer

Comment: Just in the way of an update, the answer was deleted by community vote. While this is the accepted answer, no one should take this answer as representing the community consensus.

Comment: @ChrisBaker I don't know that *there is* a consensus regarding this specific question. I've *reported* what the FAQ says (which, of course, results in shooting the messenger). An example of an area where the "official" stance and the community disagree is link-only answers. The community regularly deletes posts that if you go strictly by Shog's guidelines (which is as "official" as it gets) should not be deleted. Then end result being that if you flag a link-only answer as NAA, chances are it is going to be found helpful if *the community* handles it, but declined if a *moderator* handles it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The person doing the deleting is irrelevant. It is still rewarding the deletion of an answer.

Comment: @TylerH: It's ironic, too, because deleting your own downvoted material is the quickest way to a question ban lol

Comment: @TylerH I think there is a large difference between deleting your own answer, and the community deleting it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I agree, there is a large difference. But the point I was making is not related to *who* deletes it, rather that you are *rewarded* for deleting it.

Answer (score 13):

There are two things here: the fact that this was flagged as "very low quality" (thus the review), and whether or not you should vote to delete it.

First, about the flag. "Very low quality" should be used for answers that are gibberish, incomprehensible, or otherwise would need moderator attention to delete. That's not the case here, so I declined that flag with the standard reason of

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Now about whether you should vote to delete it. For [20k users with sufficient reputation to vote to delete answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), that's a tougher call. Do you believe such an answer detracts from the question or presents information so incorrect as to warrant deletion?

Sometimes, a case can be made that a heavily downvoted answer clearly indicates what you should not do, and can be educational even if wrong. In those cases, you might think about holding off on a delete vote and letting the answer stay. Like I said, it's a judgment call. It relies on two other people to agree with you, so if there's enough of a consensus that it has to go there's probably a good reason for that.

Comment: Yes, often highlighting an anti-pattern is just as educational as showing the path of conventional wisdom.

Answer (score 7):

I agree 100% with Louis here. Deletes are for posts that are essentially non-answers. An attempt to answer a question, no matter how wrong it is, is still an answer and deserves to live in the democratic spirit of the market of ideas. For the market of ideas to work, you need both bad ideas and good ones out of which the truth emerges.

Also, my experience with answers that have a huge number of downvotes is that they are often pretty interesting and educational in some way.

Answer (score 5):

Vote to delete it. It does not need to remain as a "badge of shame" for the answerer, and indeed I believe most regular users would delete their own answer if it had a significant number of downvotes, or the answer was *verifiably incorrect*.

Sometimes as questions linger on the site for a long time and gather large numbers of views, bad answers correspondingly gather *upvotes* in proportion with the correct answers on the same question, and some of those may eventually even reach positive scores. They are better off deleted if they are blatantly wrong.

If nothing else, they lower the signal to noise ratio. On questions with 2 or 3 answers, it's easy to ignore them. On questions with 25 answers, they just get in the way while scrolling through the good stuff.

Answer (score 1):

wrong answers have value especially when identified as they can sometimes serve as a means of better delimiting the right answer.

I have self deleted a number of answers because after asking the op modifies the question which leads to a barrage of down votes.

I dont think voting to delete good answers that are wrong adds anything. But the wrong answers in themselves can be quite illuminating to how logic goes wrong.

Comment: "wrong answers have value" except when they tell you to "try this: `rm -rf /`"... IMO there should be an auto deletion threshold below which any answer is automatically deleted to avoid keeping dangerous answers; given enough downvotes an answer should be auto deleted.

Comment: id argue that's not a wrong answer that's pure dangerous and could be considered malicious. That is a situation where a vote to delete would be appropriate. Problem with a 'threshold' is definition and also misuse of its application by the more overzealous on here.